# App rejected because of hidden whenever ad content is not being served by iAd

Tags: iphone, xcode, iad, appstore-approval

My app just got rejected because "The banner within the app should be hidden whenever ad content is not being served by iAd."  Then they supply this sample code;

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // assumes the banner view is at the top of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

Now my iAd displays at the bottom of the screen not the top.  Also I wanted to take into count 3.5 vs 4 inch screens so here is my code;

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

        if(result.height == 1136){
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 498, -banner.frame.size.height);
        }else{
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 410, -banner.frame.size.height);
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

The really annoying part is that my codes works correctly on my test iPhone and in the iOS simulator.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your banner is in the bottom, you should sum `banner.frame.size.height` instead of substract to hide the banner. There is no need to do extra calculations for different screens.

So, this should be enough:

```
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
```